# Pattern recognition - difficulty

Tags: 3d, gesture-recognition

I need to decide which semestral project to start working on. I have the opportunity to work on real-time pattern recognition in 3D space, but I have no previous experiences. I would like to ask, how hard is it to implement usable pattern recognition system in 3D space. Imagine something like drawing number 2 and the program can tell, that it is a number 2 - but in 3D and real-time. I would use the Leap Motion, which provides developers with loads of data about fingers and palm position, speed, various vectors etc. and I would like to record and then detect various hand gestures (patterns) like "thumbs up", "peace sign", "middle finger" etc.
The problem is that I don't know, how hard this could be.

I am in second year of my university - linear algebra, mathematical analysis, statistics and some other math should not be a problem.
I should be able to program in c#, java, R, Prolog and Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Long story short: robust pattern recognition in 2D is not trivial, and trying to extend that to 3D can be very hard. Many problems in the field remain poorly solved. In any case you need to narrow down the problem as much as you can.

Here's an idea: try breaking a scene into plane fits, cuboids, and ellipsoids. From that segmentation, and perhaps using a "bag of words" approach to establish some relationships between objects, try to identify some objects: a beach ball, a whiteboard, and so on.

Another possibility is to make the most robust algorithm you can that can track a uniquely shaped object under a variety of conditions. For example, identify and count the number of Coke bottles in a room. (This would probably only work within 1 - 2 meters of the sensor.) If you vary lighting, move the Coke bottles to different rooms, or have someone walk around with the Coke bottle(s) in hand, you'll quickly discover that this can be a tricky problem.

The last I checked, the Leap sensor wouldn't be a good fit for pattern/shape recognition unless your data will simply be hand and finger positions. The Kinect v2 would give you raw 3D data as well as a nice library for skeleton tracking, gesture recognition, and so on.

With only a few months to complete a task like this it's nice to think of a cool problem to solve, but make sure that intermediate solutions along the way are at least somewhat useful. Also do your best to define tolerances, parameters, recognition rates, and other details in advance--write them down. This will be a huge help in tracking progress.